# How to make Python curses overlay not transparent?

Tags: python, curses

By default a Python curses overlay is transparent, where any non character space shows the window below. Even when adding a ' ' character, it still shows the character below.

Is there a way to have an overlay's space (' ') characters hide the window below?  I will be removing the window at a later point and do not want to destory the data that is on the lower window (which works correctly when the space is a non empty character).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the behavior I was looking for is what panels are for.

> Panels are windows with the added feature of depth, so they can be >stacked on top of each other, and only the visible portions of each window >will be displayed. Panels can be added, moved up or down in the stack, and >removed.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.panel.html

Answer (score 0):

Likely you are referring to the function [overlay](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_overlay.3x.html), rather than some terminal configuration issue.  The documentation agrees with your comment:

> The  **overlay**  and **overwrite** routines overlay *srcwin* on top
>   of *dstwin*.  *scrwin* and *dstwin* are not required to  be  the
>   same  size;  only  text  where  the two windows overlap is
>   copied.  The difference is that **overlay** is non-destructive
>   (blanks are not copied) whereas **overwrite** is destructive.

Python's [curses binding](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) also has [**overwrite**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.overwrite), which sounds more like what you want.